# NHibernate, expression trees, and eliminating repetition

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

We have implemented a security layer around our NHibernate persistence layer in a way that hopes to prevent a user from even receiving an object back from the database if he shouldn't have access to it.  That security layer looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Secure<T>(this Queryable<T> query){
    //if T does not implement ISecurable, then return query
    //else
        return query.Where(expressionFactory.GetExpression(securityKey));
}
```

We essentially restrict access to our ISession by wrapping it with a decorator that calls ISession.Query().Secure().

So we have numerous types that return an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, such that we can pass it to Where():

```
public class DocumentSecurityExpressionFactory : ISecurityExpressionFactory<Document> {
    public Expression<Func<Document, bool>> GetExpression(SecurityKey key) {
        return doc => doc.MasterDocument.Compartments.Where(c => c.AssociatedCompartment.Type != ProgramTypes.AccessGroup) //Look at non-access group compartments for access
                        .All(c => key.Compartments.Contains(c.AssociatedCompartment.ID))
                    && (
            //person has to be either NTK 
                        doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Count() == 0
                        || doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => p.PersonID == key.PersonID)
                        || doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => key.AccessGroups.Contains(p.CompartmentID))
                        );
    }
}

public class DocumentSummarySecurityExpressionFactory : ISecurityExpressionFactory<DocumentSummary> {
    public Expression<Func<DocumentSummary, bool>> GetExpression(SecurityKey key) {
        return doc => doc.MasterDocument.Compartments.Where(c => c.AssociatedCompartment.Type != ProgramTypes.AccessGroup)
                        .All(c => key.Compartments.Contains(c.AssociatedCompartment.ID))
                        && (
                          doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Count() == 0
                        || doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => p.PersonID == key.PersonID)
                        || doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => key.AccessGroups.Contains(p.CompartmentID))
                           );
    }
}

public class LatestDocumentVersionSecurityExpressionFactory : ISecurityExpressionFactory<LatestDocumentVersion> {
    public Expression<Func<LatestDocumentVersion, bool>> GetExpression(SecurityKey key) {
        return version => version.BaseDocument.MasterDocument.Compartments.Where(c => c.AssociatedCompartment.Type != ProgramTypes.AccessGroup)
                            .All(c => key.Compartments.Contains(c.AssociatedCompartment.ID))
                            && (
                                version.BaseDocument.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Count() == 0
                                || version.BaseDocument.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => p.PersonID == key.PersonID)
                                || version.BaseDocument.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => key.AccessGroups.Contains(p.CompartmentID))
                            );
    }
}
```

And there are actually several more for different types that look just like this.

The problem here should be clear:  each of our entities that does this is essentially the same.  They each have a reference to a MasterDocument object, on which all the logic is done.  Repeating this code totally sucks (and it all sits in one file so they can all change together if they ever do).

I feel like I *should* be able to just tell a method how to get the MasterDocument from type T, and then have a generalized method that builds the expression.  Something like this:

```
public static class ExpressionFactory {
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, MasterDocument>> mdSource, SecurityKey key) {
        return t => {
             var md = mdSource.Compile()(t);
             return md.Compartments.Where(c => c.AssociatedCompartment)...
        };
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
public class DocumentSecurityExpressionFactory : ISecurityExpressionFactory<Document> {
    public Expression<Func<Document, bool>> GetExpression(SecurityKey key) {
        return ExpressionFactory.Get<Document>(doc => doc.MasterDocument, key);
    }
}
```

Now, I understand why this code doesn't work.  What I can't figure out is how to build up this expression tree correctly in order to vastly simplify our code.  I imagine I could pass in the `Expression<Func<T, MasterDocument>> mdSource` like that and then use the Expression API to build it out with MemberAccessExpressions and such, but I'm anticipating the mess that would look like, and I'm not sure what would be the lesser evil.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a `Compose` method that can compose one expression with another:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

Which uses the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
public static class ExpressionFactory 
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Get<T>(
         Expression<Func<T, MasterDocument>> mdSource, SecurityKey key) 
    {
        return mdSource.Compose(document => 
            document.Compartments.Where(c => c.AssociatedCompartment.Type != ProgramTypes.AccessGroup)
                    .All(c => key.Compartments.Contains(c.AssociatedCompartment.ID))
                    && (
                      doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Count() == 0
                    || doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => p.PersonID == key.PersonID)
                    || doc.MasterDocument.NeedToKnowAccessList.Any(p => key.AccessGroups.Contains(p.CompartmentID))
                       );

    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks so much.  As an aside: for one of the expressions, the property for the MasterDocument is nested several properties down (e.g. doc.PropA..PropB.MasterDocument), and in that case, the possibility exists that PropA is null.  Normally, we return true if PropA is null, and I thought I would have to work that into the expression somehow.  But actually, it turns out not to be necessary.  It works without the check, even though I might expect a NullReferenceException.  Any explanation for that?

Comment: @MarcChu SQL handles null values differently.  It simply propogates null when you try to perform an operation on a null value instead of crashing.  When you try to get the `PropB` value of a `null` value it just returns `null`, instead of throwing.  Had the code been executed as C# code, and not translated into SQL, you'd have had to deal with `null` explicitly.